# How to add WIDTH & HEIGHT in tep_image in OSCommerce

Tags: php, oscommerce

This is what I have:

```
echo tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . "arText.png", "ALTERNATE TEXT HERE");
```

The output is this:

```
img src="THIS-IS-THE-IMAGE-LOCATION" alt="ALTERNATE TEXT HERE" title="ALTERNATE TEXT HERE"
```

My question is that I want to add `WIDTH` & `HEIGHT` of the image in tep_image function in OSCommerce. So the new output would be like this:

```
img src="THIS-IS-THE-IMAGE-LOCATION" alt="ALTERNATE TEXT HERE" title="ALTERNATE TEXT HERE" WIDTH="Sizepx" HEIGHT="Sizepx"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass width and height as extra parameters to
`tep_image()` function, the function already support them. From [**`documentation:`**](http://www.oscdox.com/crossx/nav.html?_functions/index.html)

> tep_image($src, $alt = '', $width = '', $height = '', $parameters = '')   X-Ref
>   The HTML image wrapper function

So it will look like

```
echo tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . "arText.png", "ALTERNATE TEXT HERE", "width_here", "height_here");
```